# Highcharts: How to represent time of the day on x axis in HH:MM:SS format?

Tags: highcharts

I have a table in this form

```
Time        FR    IT     DE
00:00:09    1     2      12
00:00:18    1     0      0
00:00:28    1     3      11
```

I am trying to plot this data using highcharts. Here is my config

```
data = {
    "title": {
        "text": "Concurrency"
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "title": {
            "text": "Number of Employees"
        }
    },
    "legend": {
        "layout": "vertical",
        "align": "right",
        "verticalAlign": "middle"
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "name": "FR",
            "data": data_fr
        },
        {
            "name": "IT",
            "data": data_it
        },
        {
            "name": "DE",
            "data": data_de
        }
    ],
}
```

The time field represents time of the day in `HH:MM:SS` for a single day. And the rest of the columns are the series data that I need to plot on Y axis as line charts. Now, the number of rows in this table is quite large around 5000. I want to plot the time on x axis but I dont want to show every entry. I want to show only the hours on the x axis. For example, 1 am, 2 am, 3 am etc even though the `Time` column contains so many time entries. How can I accomplish this?

Also, is there any way I can smoothen my line plots? Because with so many values the graph has lots of sharp edges.

Comment: Can you explain the part 'I do not want to show every entry'? Do you want to sum / group the entries within the same hour? For data grouping within the same hour you have two options: use Highstock or group the data on your own before the chart is rendered.

Comment: @morganfree I want to show the graph but on the x axis I don't want to show the label for every x axis value. For example I will over 5000 x axis values but instead of showing them all on the x axis I just want to show a label every half an hour. Like HH:MM values every half an hour 00:00, 00:30, 01:00, 01:30 instead of all the x axis values 00:00:19, 00:00:18, 00:00:28. But I want the plot to consider all the values. Basically I don't want to make it too cluttered

Comment: You can control it with tick options - tickPositions, tickPositioner, tickInterval, tickAmount, etc. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions See the example http://jsfiddle.net/n6Latscx/

Comment: Thanks! But I didn't understand where do I provide the data for my x axis? For every value on y axis, there is a value on x axis as well. In the series array, I am providing name and data for y axis series. But where do I need to put the same for my x axis values ?

Comment: My x axis values are strings but they need to be interpreted as time. So I believe I will need to convert them to date object first by attaching a dummy date with the time values. But the intervals between the x axis values are not same. So, I need to be able to provide those as an array where the size of the array will be same as the size of all the series arrays for y axis values

Comment: @morganfree I figured it out. Had to put the x and y values in each of the series. So currently the `data` in my series was array of integers but I had to change it to array of objects with `x` and `y` as keys of each object. x contained the timestamp and y contained the value. I will put it as an answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the time from string to a timestamp (milliseconds from epoch) field. Once done that, I was able to provide the config option:

```
"xAxis": {
    "type": "datetime"
}
```

With this config, Highcharts automatically took care of the clutter from x axis. It showed the labels on x axis at regular intervals, like 2 hours apart.

Then another doubt that I had was how to provide the series data with both x and y axis values. Earlier I was only providing y axis values like this:

```
"series": [
    {
        "name": "CC_FR",
        "data": [10, 23, 11]
    },
```

I had to change the `data` array from array of numbers to array of objects with each object having `x` and `y` keys and values. Like this:

```
"series": [
    {
        "name": "CC_FR",
        "data": [
          { "x": 1528210784424 ,"y": 10 },
          { "x": 1528210803102 ,"y": 23 },
          { "x": 1528210810702 ,"y": 11 }
        ],
        "turboThreshold": 0
    },
```

The `"turboThreshold": 0` was needed in my case because the length of `data` array was more than 1000. I also added the config option:

```
"chart": {
   "zoomType": 'x'
},
```

This made my chart zoomable and whenever I would zoom in, the labels on the x axis were dynamically rendered without any need from my end to bother about the clutter.